# How to open module on a different subdomain?

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I have a custom module that I did, let's say:

```
www.domain.com/module/abc/index.php
```

I would like this module to actually open from:

```
cdn.domain.com/module/abc/index.php
```

Right now what happens is if I access `cdn.domain.com` it automatically redirects to `www.domain.com`, but I need it to stay on the cdn subdomain. How can I do this ?